# bootstrap 4 fixed navigation bar with 2 rows with centered brand image in the first row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please tell me, how can I create bootstrap 4 fixed navigation bar with 2 rows with the centered brand image in the first row like https://www.newyorker.com/ (*with change size of the image after scroll down*) and navigation menu in the second-bottom row? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/aRyORP) :)

If you view the example here in stackoverflow, do view it full page :)

```js
$(window).scroll(()=>{
  let distance = $('#header').offset().top;
  if(distance > 150){
    $('#logo').addClass('header-image-scroll');
    $('#nav-collection').addClass('navbar-scroll');
  }
  else {
    $('#logo').removeClass('header-image-scroll');
    $('#nav-collection').removeClass('navbar-scroll');
  }
})
```

```css
#header {
  height: 120px;
}

#nav-collection {
  transition: margin 300ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: .80rem;
}

#nav-collection li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#logo{
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.header-image-scroll{
  transform: scale(0.7);
}

.navbar-scroll {
  margin-top: -25px;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top bg-white">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <button class="navbar-toggler my-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-center text-center ml-lg-2 ml-0" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row mb-md-1 mt-md-0 mb-3 mt-2">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <div id="header" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <img src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/The_New_Yorker_logo.png" id="logo">
                </div>
              </li>
           </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center w-100 border-top border-bottom font-weight-bold" id="nav-collection">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Culture</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Books</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business & Tech</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Humor</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cartoons</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Magazine</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Video</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Podcasts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two `navbar` to achieve what you are trying to do.

Use the Bootstrap class `mx-auto,ml-auto` to aligning items center/left.

[Check out the CodePen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaeXJr?editors=1100)

Comment: I need both navbar fixed with "fixed-top" style, when I add this style to nav I have both navigation bar on the same place, first is not visible

Comment: I have updated the code, please check the code pen. @termix

Comment: Hi this codepen doesn't work for me. :(